# Evitar que youtube pierda la señal en tv

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Hola hice un sitio web para unos tvs, estos reproducen una lista de reproducion y otras cosas, pero la cosa es que cuando termina de reproducir el ciclo(son dos videos de 2-3 minutos) se cae la señal y cuando se vuelve a conectar reproduce videos que nada que ver, yo pienso que la perdida de conexion es lo que causa que se reproduzca otro video que no esta en la lista, ya que en mi pc cuando termina el ciclo vuelve al primer video es decir se reproduce en ciclo.

Supongo que es configuracion de los tvs pero igual les mostrare mi codigo y gracias por la ayuda.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="content">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="google" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name=”robots” content=”noimageindex”>
<title>IQ para todos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<script>


 // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(idVideo) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          playerVars : {
                listType:'playlist',
                list: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN',
                loop: true
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == 0) {
          player.loadVideoById({videoId:'qUGY0rWZu4Q'});
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }






var inicio =true;
function startTime() {
  if(inicio) {

    inicio=false;
    realizaProceso();
  }

    var today = new Date();
    var hr = today.getHours();
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    var sec = today.getSeconds();
    ap = (hr < 12) ? "<span>a.m.</span>" : "<span>p.m.</span>";
    hr = (hr == 0) ? 12 : hr;
    hr = (hr > 12) ? hr - 12 : hr;
    //Add a zero in front of numbers<10
    hr = checkTime(hr);
    min = checkTime(min);
    sec = checkTime(sec);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min  + " " + ap;

    var months = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
    var days = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'];
    var curWeekDay = days[today.getDay()];
    var curDay = today.getDate();
    var curMonth = months[today.getMonth()];
    var curYear = today.getFullYear();
    var date = curWeekDay+", "+curDay+" "+curMonth+" "+curYear;
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    //validarCambios();
    var time = setTimeout(function(){ startTime() }, 500);



}
setInterval("validarCambios();", 10000);
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}




function validarCambios(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {
      if(response.estado['id']>$("body").data("id")) {
       // $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
        //realizaProceso();
        location.reload();
      }
    } 
  });
}

function realizaProceso(){
  var parametros = {};
  $.ajax({
    data:  parametros,
    url:   'controller/index.php',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(request);
         console.log(status);
         console.log(error);
    },
    success:  function (response) {

      /*var randomColor = '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
      $('#resultado').css({
        'background-color' : randomColor,
      });*/
      $("body").attr("data-year", response.estado['year']);
      $("body").attr("data-month", response.estado['month']);
      $("body").attr("data-day", response.estado['day']);
      $("body").attr("data-hour", response.estado['hour']);
      $("body").attr("data-minute", response.estado['minute']);
      $("body").attr("data-id", response.estado['id']);
      $(".loader").hide();
      $(".carousel-congratulations").html(response.congratulations);
      $(".title-cumple").html(response.titleBirthday);
      $(".carousel-birthdays").html(response.birthdays);
      $(".title-events").html(response.titleEvent);
      $(".carousel-events").html(response.events);
      window.history.pushState("", "", '/iq/pru/');
    }
  });


}




</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()" style="background: #154482;">
<div class="pantalla">
  <div class="mod-left fleft">
    <div class="video fleft">
      <!--<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RQMAn68hvYY?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->
      <div id="player"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cumeve">
      <div class="cumple fleft">
        <div class="title-cumple" > <span class="fel">Feliz</span> Cumpleaños</div>
        <div class="cont-cumple">

          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-birthdays">
            </div>
            <!-- AQUI VAN LOS CUMPLEAÑOS-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="events fleft">
        <div class="title-events"> <span class="fel">Próximos </span>Eventos</div>
        <div class="content-events" style="padding: 1em;">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7100">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-events">
              <!-- AQUI VAN LOS EVENTOS -->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mod-right fleft">
    <div class="logo"><img src="admin/images/logo-iq.png" width="200" height="42" /></div>
    <div class="mt30">
      <div class="todos-t fleft">IQ para todos
        <div class="gal">
          <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="8350">
            <div class="carousel-fade carousel-congratulations">
            <!-- AQUI VAN LAS FELICITACIONES -->


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_hour">
      <div class="fhour">
        <div id="clockdate">
          <div class="clockdate-wrapper">
            <div id="date"></div>
            <div id="clock"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" ></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

esta es la url donde esta alojado: [Pantallas TV](http://seadoglabs.com/iq/pru/)

Answer (score 1):

esto se da porque termino la lista de reproduccion y continua al siguiente video segun los gustos del usuario
en este caso intentas enviarle un nuevo id pero esto es solo para repodrucir un solo video.
intenta reiniciando la playlist una vez termine con ella ejemplo:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(idVideo) {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: {
            listType: 'playlist',
            list: 'PLn5lEmVWb0R-YLCFw2FYwptEqkZMRheFN',
            loop: true,
            controls: 0
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        currentIndex = event.target.getPlaylistIndex();
    }

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        if (currentIndex == (playlist.length - 1)) {
            player.playVideo();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ya lo implemente voy a decirle que prueben y te respondo si sirvio o no

Comment: En pc funciona bien, falte ver en tv, ya me toca esperar al cliente, por ahora dare flecha arriba ya cuando el cliente responda el chulo... gracias.

Comment: No funciono en tv me acaban de mandar una imagen que tiene el mismo problema que antes

Comment: sale error en playlist

Comment: home.php:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: playlist is not defined
    at onPlayerStateChange (home.php:59)
    at M.h.G (www-widgetapi.js:48)
    at Y.h.o (www-widgetapi.js:92)
    at Y.h.H (www-widgetapi.js:106)
    at Wa.g (www-widgetapi.js:81)
    at Oa.f (www-widgetapi.js:70)